# One line conversion of string to List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, string, list

This is a rather simple, but annoying problem I am facing.

There are many places in my application that can use either one or many strings... so to say.
I have used a List of string by default.

But every time I have a single string, I am doing this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add(myString);
```

A simple `myString.ToList()` does not work since it converts into a list of characters and not a list with one string.
Is there an efficient one line way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using collection initializer:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>{myString};
```

**Update.** Or, as suggested in comments,

```
var myList = new List<string>{myString};
```

Comment: Thanks! Saves close to 20 lines!

Comment: or even better
`var myList = new List<string>{myString};`

Comment: You could wrap this in a method or extension method to make it even more succinct: `mystring.ToList()`...

Comment: @JeffRSon, ok, it's subjective, but I like it more. For me it's even more readable - you see `var`, you know that your type is taken from right part of expression, and you don't repeating yourself

Answer (score 4):

I don't at all think that it's worth doing the following, BUT if you really are often creating string lists from single strings, and you really *really* want the shortest syntax possible - then you could write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static List<string> AsList(this string self)
    {
        return new List<string> { self };
    }
}
```

Then you would just do:

```
var list = myString.AsList();
```

But like I said, it seems hardly worth it. It also may be confusable with:

```
var list = myString.ToList();
```

which (by using Linq) will create a list of chars from the chars in the string.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer, but you came first ... I considered making it more general, `public static List<T> ToSingletonList<T>(this T value)
      {
        return new List<T> { value };
      }` but of course that's not useful if he only needs this for `string`.